# Changing colours of specific table view cells without changing others

Tags: swift

The main issue is that when I try to add an image to a cell like a pdf icon or change the colour of the cell text based on the cell value it changes cells that I do not intend to change. Also, between simulators it appears different. For instance the XSmax works fine not because of my hacky fixes but the xs is all messed up with multiple cells that I do not want changed changed.

I have tried debugging the code, and even trying to fix it in a very hacky way by just reseting the cells that were affected.

```swift
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell: UITableViewCell
       let fieldCellIdentifier = "FieldCell"
       if let fieldCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: fieldCellIdentifier) {
           cell = fieldCell
       }
       else {
           cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: fieldCellIdentifier)
       }
       let row = wellInfoSections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
       cell.textLabel?.text = row.label
       cell.detailTextLabel?.text = row.value
       if indexPath.section == WellSummarySections.contacts.rawValue || indexPath.section == WellSummarySections.pdf.rawValue {
           cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
       }
       if indexPath.section == WellSummarySections.pdf.rawValue {
           cell.imageView?.tintColor = PelotonGoStyle.Palette.darkRed
           cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pdf")
       }

//I just expect that only the cells I want to change to change not the cells that I do not want. Kinda vague but so is the issue.
```

Comment: *Cells are reused.* Everytime you do an `if` inside `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)`, I strongly suggest to do the opposite (like setting no image, no accessory, etc.) in the `else`.

Comment: that worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `prepareForReuse()` method on UITableView cell and set the colors back to default:

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse
```